# RealmSwiftのインストールができない。

Tags: swift, realm

いつもお世話になっております。
表題の件ですが、公式サイトの
https://realm.io/jp/docs/swift/latest/
にて、
Swift 2.1.1をDynamicFrameworkでRealmSwiftをインストールしました。
ところが、下記のようにRealmSwift.frameworkとRealm.frameworkに ? が出てしまい、コードを入力してもエラーが立ってしまいます。
どうやら、正しくインストールできていないようです。
お解りになる方がいらっしゃったらお教え下さい。
因みに、
http://qiita.com/YukiAsano/items/ac2d949aafe9b5755cf6
も参考にしました。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

```
import UIKit
import RealmSwift
class User: Object {
    dynamic var id = 0
    dynamic var name = ""    
    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "id"        
        let realm = try! Realm()

        let user = User()
        user.id = 0
        user.name = "Name1"
        try! realm.write {
            realm.add(user)
        }
    }
}
```

上記のコードを書くと、
Invalid redecoration of 'User'
とエラーになります。

これはRealmSwiftによるものでは無いのですか？

コードそのものに問題があるのであれば、RealmSwiftは正常にインストール出来ていると考えて良いのですか？

Comment: 手動でないといけないのですか？Cocoapodsを使ってはいかがでしょうか？

Comment: CococaPods 0.39.0以降をインストールしてください。
Podfileにuse_frameworks!と追加します。そしてアプリケーションとテストのターゲットに対してpod 'RealmSwift'と追加してください。
コマンドラインでpod installを実行してください。
CocoaPodsによって作られた.xcworkspaceファイルを開いてください。
https://realm.io/jp/docs/swift/latest/

Comment: 「RealmSwift.frameworkとRealm.frameworkに ? が出てしまい」＞Project Navigatorのその位置に出てくる`?`は、`M`(修正された)、`A`(追加された)などと同類のバージョン管理の状態を表す文字で、`?`「バージョン管理されていない」ことを示しています。Frameworkが正しくインストールできているかどうかとは関係ありません。「コードを入力してもエラーが立ってしまいます。」＞どのような入力をするとどのようなエラーになるのかご記載ください。

Comment: コメント有難うございます。本文にコードとエラー内容を追加しました。よろしくお願いします。

Comment: Realmの岸川です。インストールが正常にできているかどうかは微妙ですが、エラーの内容はRealmによるものではないです。`User`のクラス定義が別のファイルにもう一つあったりしませんか？あと、`primaryKey()`メソッドの実装が`return`したあとに処理を書いているので`return`以降は実行されません。できれば、プロジェクト全体をどこかにアップロードするか help@realm.io に送ってもらえませんか？そうするとすぐに問題がわかります。